# Sobre questões superficiais

Tags: discussion, beta, questions, on-topic-definition

Eu gostaria de entender o intuito do Beta. Estou vendo muitas questões básicas que podem ser respondidas com uma simples pesquisa na internet. Perguntas como "qual o significado da palavra X?" que pode ser encontrado em vários sites dicionários na rede, já que a questão não inclui nenhum tipo de contexto. Ou perguntas como "diferença entre X, Y e Z", que pode ser solucionada da mesma forma, com uma pesquisa simples.

Afinal, o beta é realmente pra esse tipo de pergunta, de forma que seja criado uma base de conhecimento nesse site(mesmo já existindo em outros), ou deveria receber questões mais elaboradas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Acho [esta "pergunta", escrito por J.R. no FAQ do ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9346), muito bem escrito e relevante. Ele diz que em vez de perguntar simplesmente "qual é correcto?" ou "o que significa?", é melhor explica também:

- o contexto da sua pergunta;
- por que é que você tem dúvidas; e
- quais informações que você já sabe sobre o assunto, por exemplo a definição que encontrou num dicionário.

Eu entendo que fazendo isso é importante porque comunica aos leitores, de forma mais eficaz, as suas dúvidas. Muitas perguntas nos sites de StackExchange não contem uma descrição verdadeira das dúvidas do autor. E assim fica para os leitores as adivinhar.

Pode ser que no ELL perguntas são fechadas mais frequentemente do que seria bom aqui. Mas acho muito bom a filosofia de "desenvolver a pergunta".

Quando encontramos uma pergunta que parece "simples demais", podemos falar com o autor para esclarecer uma dúvida mais específica. (E quando a "dúvida verdadeira" aparece só nos comentários, é importante editar a pergunta.)

Comment: Cara, perfeita colocação da referência. O que está escrito nessa pergunta é exatamente o que estou tentando debater aqui. Ao invés dos usuários se portarem como descrito no seu último parágrafo, eles vão lá e dão um *up* na pergunta. Não tem ideia da postura errada que estão tomando. Detalhe no perfil do usuário J.R.: *"Remember, **context is everything**".* Perfeito.

Comment: Acho que @Math deveria ver isso...

Comment: O @JNat também.

Comment: Já li @DontVoteMeDown :) E eu concordo que se um usuário se preocupa em seguir essas três itens sua pergunta terá muito mais qualidade. Só que ainda acho que temos que separar o que é uma pergunta básica de uma pergunta de baixa qualidade e nos esforçar em tentar ver se existe a possibilidade de uma pergunta de baixa qualidade possa ser salva com algumas poucas edições. Talvez não seja o momento de fazer isso no beta privado, mas fazer isso no beta público, é em minha opinião, uma boa forma de atrair usuários ao invés de espantá-los.

Comment: Eu li @DontVoteMeDown. Nada do que está aqui dito vai contra o que eu disse. Eu também menciono que convém que haja pesquisa prévia, e que isso seja evidente.

Answer (score 8):

Os sites da rede Stack Exchange têm o intuito de formarem repositórios de perguntas e respostas para problemas sobre os tópicos em questão para justamente serem encontrados em motores de busca.

Se não pudermos perguntar nada que pode ser encontrado no Google, significa que não poderemos perguntar nada, pois o Google já tem tudo.

Comment: Discordo. [Isso](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/123/83) é uma pergunta sobre contexto, duvido que tenha "no Google". Agora [isso](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/137/83) eu acho completamente desnecessário, se não o site pode se tornar um [Yahoo Respostas](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070324102558AA3r4rn).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown acho que existe algo que deve ficar claro que é "pergunta simples" e "escopo". Se a pergunta estiver dentro do escopo, ela pode ser tanto simples como complicada. Você considera o segundo caso muito simples ou fora de escopo? Ou ambos? :)

Comment: Eu a considero *sem contexto* (ou escopo, se você preferir), como exemplifiquei no corpo da minha pergunta. O primeiro caso não é *simples* pois envolve um contexto, e não uma resposta pronta, que se acha em um dicionário, ao contrário da segunda questão.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown resolvi criar uma pergunta pois acredito que nosso contexto ainda não está claro, e sua pergunta se refere principalmente à "perguntas simples". Acho difícil responder sua pergunta sem sabermos qual é o nosso contexto, ou escopo.

Comment: Sim, o título em si não dá muito contexto(até alterei pra tentar melhorar), mas você pode tentar ler a pergunta toda pra entender o escopo, e tentar argumentar melhor seu ponto de vista.

Answer (score 8):

Como foi dito nas outras respostas, o objectivo dos sites da rede Stack Exchange é a criação de repositórios de perguntas e respostas *de qualidade*. Fazer perguntas que podem ter respostas noutro lado é permitido e encorajado, uma vez que a criação dos referidos repositórios só pode ter lugar se conseguirmos agregar o máximo de conteúdo no site — note-se que a prática de fazer uma pergunta sabendo a resposta, e consequentemente responder à mesma [é uma prática encorajada](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Quando um site é lançado, o objectivo é criar uma base sólida de utilizadores, perguntas e respostas — é normal que nesta fase surja um número de perguntas que são facilmente respondíveis maior do que noutras fases da vida do site, tanto porque alguns utilizadores querem tentar ganhar reputação fácil, como porque a comunidade vai tentar fazer os possíveis para ver o volume de perguntas e respostas aumentar rapidamente. No entanto, isto não quer dizer que a comunidade tenha que ser branda com publicações que lhes parecem de fraca qualidade.

"Não permitir" ou consequentemente "fechar" perguntas fáceis ou de fraca qualidade não são as únicas opções. É importante fazer a distinção entre fechar uma pergunta e votar negativamente na mesma: a primeira serve para que perguntas que não fazem parte do âmbito do site, são duplicados, são demasiado amplas, etc. sejam postas num estado de suspensão para que o autor as possa tentar melhorar para que a comunidade tenha melhores possibilidades de o ajudar (e para que a pergunta seja útil para a comunidade também); a segunda serve para a comunidade demonstrar ao autor que a sua pergunta não mostra esforço de pesquisa prévia, não é clara ou não é útil. É importante que a comunidade vote liberalmente *nos dois sentidos* para que se estabeleçam padrões de qualidade.

Tendo dito isto, parece-me que perguntas como "qual o significado da palavra X?" *podem* fazer algum sentido, sobretudo se forem feitas em inglês ou se se referirem a diferenças ou nuances entre dialectos. O que quero dizer com isto é que nem sempre há traduções directas para todas as palavras, e uma vez que a língua está intrinsecamente ligada à cultura, pode fazer sentido tentar perceber qual será a melhor palavra, expressão ou maneira de tentar transmitir a ideia ou sentimento associados a uma certa palavra (veja-se o caso de [saudade](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/80/15)). Se não for esse o caso, então não me parece que este site seja a ferramenta indicada para substituir um dicionário.

Em relação a perguntas como "diferença entre X, Y e Z", parece-me um pouco mais complicado. Há casos que fazem sentido, sobretudo para quem esteja a aprender a falar português (pode ser complicado de distinguir "há" e "à" para quem ainda não domine a língua). No entanto, é importante notar que algumas destas perguntas se vão basear na pronunciação das palavras, e portanto podem fazer sentido num dialecto mas não noutro, pelo que especificar o dialecto na publicação ou através de tags pode fazer sentido (ver [esta resposta aqui](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/59/15), bem como os exemplos dados na mesma).

Comment: "não mostra esforço de pesquisa prévia" e "fazer perguntas que podem ter respostas noutro lado é permitido e encorajado" não são coisas compatíveis.

Comment: Claro que são! **Podes responder à tua própria pergunta**. De qualquer modo, podem haver respostas noutro lado, mas estarem espalhadas por uma série de sítios, o que torna a pesquisa muito difícil por vezes. Nesses casos uma pessoa pode vir aqui fazer uma pergunta para tentar obter uma resposta definitiva; ou pode vir fazer a pergunta e responder à mesma para agregar essas fontes todas num só sítio. Em nenhum desses dois casos consideraria que houve falta de esforço na pesquisa prévia.

Comment: Mas como eu sei se houve ou não esse esforço? Eu na minha pergunta http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/280/o-que-%C3%A9-um-crase fui pesquisar o que era mas achei que mais gente ia querer saber o que é. Não é melhor ter a informação cá?

Comment: Melhor, como eu demonstro o esforço de pesquisar e achar que a resposta devia estar aqui?

Comment: @JorgeB. Acrescentando uma ou mais frases que justifiquem a dúvida e apresentem uma base de conhecimento do perguntador. [Um](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/242/84) e [outro](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/290/express%C3%A3o-equivalente-a-with-a-grain-of-salt) exemplo. Não se limitam ao ponto principal da pergunta.

Comment: @E_net4 mas se eu quero saber só [O que é um crase?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/280/o-que-%C3%A9-um-crase)

Comment: @JorgeB. Nessa pergunta indicaste o motivo para a dúvida. Considero-a aceitável e a comunidade no geral também. Senão, não teria pontuação positiva nos votos. Se uma pessoa ou outra não concorda... acontece. Deixemos o resto da comunidade decidir e evitar que cada situação desta leve a uma pergunta no Meta.

Comment: @E_net4 Eu não criei nenhuma pergunta no meta por isso mesmo.

Comment: @JNat desculpe mas vou discordar no ponto em relação ao *downvote* e o *close vote*. Geralmente o que se vê é o fechamento da pergunta após os votos negativos. Os votos são para indicar que algo está errado com a pergunta, e os motivos podem ser muitos. Esses motivos são contemplados pelos motivos de fechamento. Por tanto, na minha opinião, o fechamento é uma consequência da má qualidade do post, por isso os votos negativos vêm antes, mas ambas as ações tem o mesmo propósito, que é fazer o usuário melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. [1](http://www.tudosobreconcursos.com/materiais/portugues/crase-regras), [2](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint76.php) e [3](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase). Note quantas fontes que poderiam responder à sua pergunta. Achei-as numa simples pesquisa. As 3 páginas possuem conteúdo melhor(entenda por melhor explicação, por ex) do que a resposta que você assinalou em sua pergunta. É isso que estou discutindo: sua pergunta foi realmente necessária? Um usuário que veja na sua pergunta por meio de uma pesquisa vai achar ela melhor(com mais qualidade) do que as outras páginas?

Comment: @JNat Sobre as perguntas *self-answered* eu sei que são encorajadas, porém no SOPT isso fui usado para ganhar reputação. Essas prática é encorajada para que um usuário resolva uma situação que ele não encontrou na web e ninguém pode ajudá-lo, e que ele conseguiu resolver sozinho. Por exemplo essa [questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/777/75) nada mais é do que um script pronto facilmente [achado na internet](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=c%23+turn+off+computer).

Comment: @Dont Não acontece sempre. Uma pergunta demasiado ampla, p.e., deve ser fechada independentemente dos votos que tenha, até ser melhorada e redifinida pelo OP. Por oposição, uma pergunta pode estar perfeitamente clara e bem posta, mas eu posso achá-la perfeitamente inútil — a pergunta perde um voto, mas nada indica que ela tenha que ser fechada, ou sequer que a comunidade partilhe da minha opinião. A tua linha de pensamento só é válida quando a comunidade concorda que a pergunta não só não é útil, como não pode ser respondida no seu estado actual — aí é normal os dois votos andarem de mão dada.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown sobre esse seu último exemplo, o OP ganhou 30 pontos, é isso que arruina a comunidade?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Responder à própria pergunta, como disse, é encorajado. Desde que a pergunta e resposta sejam úteis para a comunidade, qual é o problema de o utilizador ganhar reputação também? Se não forem de qualidade, a comunidade vota negativamente, e aí o utilizador não ganha reputação — ou pelo menos é suposto ser assim. Para que o sistema funcione como é suposto, basta que todos os utilizadores votem liberalmente, _e nos dois sentidos_ — muitas vezes parece não haver problema em votar positivamente, mas negativamente é outra conversa... (talvez porque também se perca 1 ponto?)

Comment: @Math não, mas se cada usuário postar meia dúzia de perguntas desse tipo talvez sim.

Comment: @JNat tem razão, o problema é a palavra *suposto*.

Comment: E perguntas que pedem o significado de palavras homófonas, como [esta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/168)? É cedo para bater o martelo sobre isso, mas vejo razões para considerar off-topic (com um motivo personalizado que precisaria ser criado).

Comment: @bfavaretto A mim não me parece que perguntas como essa tenham um lugar neste site (e neste caso não me parece fazer sentido nem se a pergunta for feita em inglês), mas é a comunidade que tem que decidir isso. Agir sobre as perguntas é o primeiro passo; se não houver consenso, é trazer para o Meta para tentar perceber quais são os pontos de vista que levam a que não haja consenso. É importante perceber que nunca é cedo de mais para tomar decisões em relação a estes assuntos — não adiem só porque o site é novo.

Comment: @JNat independente da sua posição em relação a isto, que eu até concordo com ela, fico contente de ver como você se posiciona em relação a comunidade. Eu queria que todos na SE fossem assim. Buscando a qualidade sempre, mas fazendo isto democraticamente. Infelizmente não tivemos isto em outros momentos/site(s).

Comment: @bigown É uma pena que nem toda comunidade sai do jeito que você quer, mas assim é a vida

Comment: É principalmente uma pena apenas um site sair do jeito que eu não quero e os outros saírem do jeito que sempre foram criados ma rede.

Answer (score 5):

Fiz essa exata [mesma pergunta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21263/49940) lá no Area 51, na época dos commits.

O que me disseram é que a intenção é criar um ajuntamento de informações em um só lugar, pra assim facilitar a procura.

Porém acho que deve ter um limite para isso, por que questões simples e muito comuns até que vai, porque são dúvidas, e dúvidas essas que muitas pessoas têm, mas significado/tradução de palavras que não têm nenhuma dificuldade ou dúvida atrelada a elas, na minha opinião, não seria nada mais do que preguiça em procurar em um dicionário (mesmo sendo muito mais rápido e fácil do que perguntar).

Quanto a perguntas sobre "diferença entre X, Y ou Z", depende muito. Por que têm certos sinônimos que causam essa dúvida, mesmo. Mas eu acho que perguntas meio óbvias como "qual o certo: estrupar ou estuprar", são um tanto desnecessárias.

Comment: *preguiça em procurar em um dicionário (mesmo sendo muito mais rápido e fácil do que perguntar)* algumas vezes acontece de as pessoas perguntarem coisa óbvias em busca de reputação.

Comment: Exatamente, ainda mais agora que é início de private beta e todo mundo procura subir a reputação o mais cedo possível.

Comment: Isso aconteceu no SOPT e realmente me desanimou de participar. Usuários fazendo perguntas superficiais, as vezes perguntando e respondendo a própria pergunta como se fosse um blog para farmar reputação. A maioria dos high-rep users de lá hoje são por causa disso. Acho ridículo. Por isso perguntei, para mim está(ou pode estar) acontecendo o mesmo aqui.

Comment: É essa a pergunta sobre a qual você se refere? http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/21263/49940

Comment: Sim, essa mesmo.

Comment: A "diferença entre X, Y ou Z" pode realmente ser uma dúvida pertinente ou fundamentada por quem perguntou de tal maneira que a resposta não será apenas uma definição comum destas palavras.
Até perguntas de dicionário podem ser válidas aqui, devido a diferenças culturais e entre dicionários. Portanto, concordo com o que foi dito aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Como em tudo, a resposta depende do caso específico. Mas penso que devemos definir qual é a posição padrão, e quais são as exceções. O botão de downvote diz precisamente "This question does not show any research effort (...)", e penso que essa orientação é um bom ponto de partida para construirmos um recurso de qualidade e que atraia especialistas.

Perguntas com respostas simples mas que escondem detalhes mais complicados por trás são possíveis exceções, e devemos ter a capacidade de as identificar e tolerar. Mas perguntas como [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mau-e-mal), [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/31/obrigado-vs-obrigada) ou [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/136/n%C3%B3s-vamos-se-divertir-ou-n%C3%B3s-vamos-nos-divertir), sinceramente são excessivamente básicas, não convidam respostas detalhadas ou *insightful* (à falta de melhor palavra em PT), e receio que afastem leitores especialistas e até mesmo amadores com interesse moderado na língua.

**edit**: após ler a resposta do JNat, ocorreu-me que de facto se as perguntas de exemplo acima tivessem sido feitas em inglês, não me faria tanta impressão. Talvez esse princípio (perguntas básicas aceites apenas se feitas em inglês) seja uma forma interessante de formalizar um dos tipos de exceção que como comunidade concordamos em aceitar. Claro que, mais uma vez, não seria uma regra absoluta, mas algo que nos desse uma orientação ao tomarmos decisões sobre como lidar com esse conteúdo.

Comment: Não sei porque do down vote. Estou totalmente de acordo.

Answer (score -1):

Isto é vício do SOpt. Lá foi incentivado postar qualquer porcaria. A maioria dos usuários aqui vêm de lá. Então esse será mais um *site* contaminado.

Eu acho que perguntas simples podem ser feitas mas o ideal é que não seja agora. Mas esquece, elas serão feitas.

Foi o tempo que a SE se preocupava com a qualidade do conteúdo e queria que o *site* iniciasse na sua melhor forma.

É uma triste verdade.

Comment: Exatamente! Se for pra ser mais um yahoo respostas pra que iniciar um novo site então, certo? O [english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/) ainda tem esse controle de qualidade. Ele não aceitam questões superficiais.

Comment: Some related comments on [this question](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/161/o-que-%c3%a9-um-verbo-defectivo) and [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22775148#22775148)

Comment: I also asked a separate meta question [here](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-try-to-populate-this-site-with-questions).

Comment: Sério que você acha que existe momento ideal para algumas perguntas serem feitas e outras não? Pelo que eu bem me lembre você é a favor das perguntas simples, mas sua resposta aqui me faz parecer que você é em maior parte contra. Outro ponto é: as perguntas simples seriam o que faz você achar que baixa a qualidade no SOpt, ou estou equivocado?

Comment: Recebi agora há pouco o email do SE (atrasado) sobre a graduação pro private beta, e nele diz: *"Ask difficult, specific questions — the kind of questions pros and experts ask each other, not the kind of questions novices ask pros, because a site full of pros and experts will attract everybody, but a site full of novices rapidly becomes boring. No easy questions, no survey questions, no polls, no intro-level/basic questions, no unanswerable hypothetical questions."*  Essa descrição se parece com algum SE em português?

Comment: @BrunoLopes a SE hoje não se importa nem com o que ela mesma diz. Estes textos foram escritos num tempo que eles pensavam diferente, que eles monitoravam e faziam que o começo do site fosse o mais organizado possível, para criar um padrão ótimo. Hoje, o texto está aí ou porque esqueceram de mudar ou porque fica bonito dizer publicamente que eles querem qualidade.

Comment: Embora eu concorde que devíamos evitar um número excessivo de perguntas simplistas e investir em perguntas mais profissionais, esta resposta acrescenta lamentações que eu considero dispensáveis. O site ainda agora nasceu, talvez não da forma como desejávamos, mas vamos conservando e mantendo o site saudável dentro dos nossos limites.

Comment: Quem avisa, amigo é. Fique com suas esperanças.

Comment: @big, sorry, could not resist :D http://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPlK.jpg